# Porting Android Application to Iphone

Tags: iphone

I have implemented an application on Android using phonegap and Jqtouch. Its working fine.

I would like to test the same on iPhone. Could you please suggest me , how to test it on IPhone? Does it required any additional components to test it?

Comment: It requires that you rewrite it. Buy a Mac and download the iPhone SDK. It has everything you need to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go on http://www.phonegap.com/start/ if you had used phonegap and check for ios.
Definitely, you need MAC, developer certificate ($99 atleast), XCode (4 gb)
and it is not easy to upload on app-store as in android market.

Comment: What do you mean it's not as easy? What's the hard part? The interface seems simple enough to me... Or do you mean Apple doesn't approve all of the craptastic apps that get in the Android store?

Comment: you know, it will take no time to upload on android and atleast 7 days for app-store if it is new app. Even wrong screenshots of app can delay 7 days of to publish on app-store. I have no idea that setContentToHTMLString was private method was delayed 7 days again. etc etc. I guess. you might faced these probs too. On android, I've never

Comment: Apple allows craptastic apps. :D , yeah Cody you really right, I had also seen some apps.  but sometimes, it exaggerates issues while uploading